# How to extract the n-th maximum/minimum value in a column of a DataFrame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max, min

I would like to obtain the n-th minimum or the n-th maximum value from numerical columns in the `DataFrame` in pandas.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3.0, 2.0, 4.0, 1.0],'b': [1.0, 4.0 , 2.0, 3.0]})

     a    b
0  3.0  1.0
1  2.0  4.0
2  4.0  2.0
3  1.0  3.0
```

The third largest value in column `a` is 2 and the second smallest value in column `b` is also 2.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `nlargest`/`nsmallest` -

```
df    
     a    b
0  3.0  1.0
1  2.0  4.0
2  4.0  2.0
3  1.0  3.0
```

```
df.a.nlargest(3).iloc[-1]
2.0
```

Or,

```
df.a.nlargest(3).iloc[[-1]]

1    2.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

And, as for `b` -

```
df.b.nsmallest(2).iloc[-1]
2.0
```

Or,

```
df.b.nsmallest(2).iloc[[-1]]

2    2.0
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

Quick observation here - this sort of operation cannot be vectorised. You are essentially performing two completely different operations here.

Comment: @KrzysztofSłowiński You're welcome. Edited my answer.

Comment: @COLDSPEED it there a way to return only a single n-th maximum / minimum row or the approach is to use nlargest / nsmallest and then take the last row?

Comment: @KrzysztofSłowiński the other alternative is calling x.sort_values() and accessing the Nth largest/smallest value depending on whether you sort in ascending or descending. Either way, you must sort.

Comment: Sure, I was thinking if there was a function or a recommended way.

Comment: @KrzysztofSłowiński as of now, there is only nlargest, but there could be a nThLargest in the future :-)

Comment: Yes, exactly, if it is a common use case.

Answer (score 5):

```
df =  
     a    b
0  3.0  1.0
1  2.0  4.0
2  4.0  2.0
3  1.0  3.0

df.nlargest(3,'a')
   =2.0

df.nsmallest(2,'b')=2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

5th max: `df.a.nlargest(5).min()`
5th min: `df.a.nsmallest(5).max()`.
Tips: add param `keep` may acts better:
`df.a.nlargest(5,keep='first').min()`

Comment: This question is relatively old so thank you for this solution because it seems to be the most pythonic and clean (compared to others). How about performance? What is your experience?