# 2nd minimum value in a pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get not the min but the 2nd minimum value in the pivot table (basically the next value after the min value). How I can do?

```
pd.pivot_table(df1, values='values', index=['rows'],columns=['columns'], aggfunc=np.min)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48026397/how-to-extract-the-n-th-maximum-minimum-value-in-a-column-of-a-dataframe-in-pand

Comment: I don't need the overall nth smallest...but the nth smallest for each rows and columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the following function:

```
def min2(s):
    tbl = s.nsmallest(2)
    return tbl.iloc[1] if tbl.size > 1 else tbl.iloc[0]
```

Then pass it as *aggfunc*.

The idea is:

- generate a *Series* with *2* smalest values (ascending sort),
- take the second of them, providing there are 2 values (*if* variant),
- but there could be only a **single** source value, so if there is
  only one value, take the only existing (the first - *else* variant).

Answer (score 0):

Use custom function with sorting DataFrame by `values` and then selecting second value, if not exist (single value):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'rows':list('aaaaaa'),
    'columns':[5,3,3,9,9,9],
    'values':[1,3,5,7,2,0]


})
print (df1)
  rows  columns  values
0    a        5       1
1    a        3       3
2    a        3       5
3    a        9       7
4    a        9       2
5    a        9       0
```

---

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df1, 
                    values='values', 
                    index=['rows'],
                    columns=['columns'], aggfunc=np.min)
print (df)
columns  3  5  9
rows            
a        3  1  0
```

If not exist is returned misisng value:

```
def second(x):
    return x.iat[1] if len(x) > 1 else np.nan
```

If not exust second values is returned single value:

```
def second(x):
    return x.iat[1] if len(x) > 1 else x.iat[0]
```

---

```
print (df1.sort_values('values'))
  rows  columns  values
5    a        9       0
0    a        5       1
4    a        9       2
1    a        3       3
2    a        3       5
3    a        9       7

df = pd.pivot_table(df1.sort_values('values'), 
                    values='values', 
                    index=['rows'],
                    columns=['columns'],
                    aggfunc=second)
print (df)
columns  3  9
rows         
a        5  2
```

Because if no exist is removed column is posible use this alternative:

```
df = (df1.sort_values('values')
        .groupby(['rows','columns'])['values']
        .agg(second)
        .unstack())
print (df)
columns    3   5    9
rows                 
a        5.0 NaN  2.0
```